# Changing drupal_set_message red or yellow

Tags: 6, status-messages

I am looking to change `$errors[] = drupal_set_message(t(' Freshwater Shrimp should be a number!'));`

Into a red or yellow message at the top of the page. Looking at the [doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/6) I should do this in drupal 6

```
 $errors[] = drupal_set_message(t(' Gammarus (Freshwater Shrimp) should be a number!', 'Warning',));
```

But I have no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've put `warning` as a 2nd argument for function `t()`. Look carefully at the syntax. It should be an argument to the `drupal_set_message` function instead:

Wrong:

```
 $errors[] = drupal_set_message(t(' Gammarus (Freshwater Shrimp) should be a number!', 'Warning',));
```

Correct:

```
$errors[] = drupal_set_message(t(' Gammarus (Freshwater Shrimp) should be a number!'), 'warning');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a warning, you need to use `'warning'` type. It is **not** the same as `'Warning'` you have used. `'Warning'` is not defined, so `drupal_set_message` defaults to `'status'`. When setting options that are not meant to be human-readable, you need to remember that for a machine they are case-sensitive.

Comment: I tried this `$errors[] = drupal_set_message(t(' Cased caddisfly should be a number!', 'warning'));` with a lower `w` but I then get an error    `•warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/drupal1/includes/common.inc on line 964.
•warning: strtr() [function.strtr]: The second argument is not an array. in /var/www/html/drupal1/includes/common.inc on line 981.
`

Comment: you've put `warning` as a 2nd argument for function `t()` that's why you're getting errors. Look carefully at the syntax.